# how to get wanted result from mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Have data in mongo items collection like this:

```
> db.items.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e9d57f8b018eecfd91c785a"), "customer_id" : 1, "goods_id" : 10, "op_code" : 1, "op_value" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e9d57f8b018eecfd91c785b"), "customer_id" : 1, "goods_id" : 10, "op_code" : 1, "op_value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e9d57f8b018eecfd91c785c"), "customer_id" : 1, "goods_id" : 10, "op_code" : 2, "op_value" : 5 }
```

"op_code" field stands for plus or minus operation (value 1 for plus operation and 2 for minus), and the "op_value" field is absolute value. How can I count total value of "op_value" group by "customer_id" and "goods_id" field.

wanted result as follow:

```
# "total" field stands for sum of "op_value", "op_code" value 1 is plus while 2 is minus.
{ "_id" : { "customer_id" : 1, "goods_id" : 10}, "total" : 2 } # 5 + 2 - 5
```

mongo version is: 3.2.12

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use Aggregation pipeline `$group` stage with `$sum` operator as shown in the documentation example: [Calculate Count, Sum, and Average](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#calculate-count-sum-and-average). You can group by multiple fields as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as you expected,

```
  db.items.aggregate(
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "customer_id": "$customer_id",
                "goods_id": "$goods_id"
            },
            "pos": { 
               "$sum": { 
                   "$cond": [
                       { "$eq": [ "$op_code", 1 ] },
                       "$op_value",
                       0
                   ]
               }
            },
            "neg": { 
               "$sum": { 
                   "$cond": [
                       { "$eq": [ "$op_code", 2 ] },
                       "$op_value",
                       0
                   ]
               }
            }
        }
    },
    { "$project": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "total": { "$subtract": [ "$pos", "$neg" ] }
    }})
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer sincerely, this really works.